# How to change drawable tint of a button below api level 23 programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of drawableLeft/drawableRight of button programmatically . I have used drawable tint in my xml as mentioned below which works > api level 23 but not able to change the color < api level 23

```
 <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VIEW ALL"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_menu_black_36dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/view_all"
                android:textColor="@color/bottom_color"
                android:drawableTint="@color/bottom_color"
                />
      Button  prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);

   Drawable[] drawables  =prev.getCompoundDrawables();
         drawables[0].setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        prev.setCompoundDrawables(drawables[0],null,null,null);
```

Solution :

```
 Drawable[] drawablesprev  =prev.getCompoundDrawables();

//for drawableleft drawable array index 0  

  drawablesprev[0].setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.assessment_bottom), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

//for drawableright drawable array index 2  
drawablesprev[2].setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.assessment_bottom), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);


//for drawabletop drawable array index 1
  drawablesprev[1].setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.assessment_bottom), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: use `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat` and its `setTint(Drawable drawable, int tint)` method

Comment: can you pls give sample code for same. I m kinnda stuck here

Comment: stuck in what? What's your code?

Comment: Drawable[] drawables  =prev.getCompoundDrawables();
         drawables[0].setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        prev.setCompoundDrawables(drawables[0],null,null,null); this is code how to change this with the one which u have mentionend

Comment: did you see my first comment? use [DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`, so you are multiplying colors. assuming (name of your drawable) your icon is black - `#000000` or as `int` it will be `0`. then `0 * GRAY` (or any other color) will always give you `0`, so still black...

try other `PorterDuff.Mode`s, e.g. `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` or `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN`

your current code will probably work with white version of icon, which should be colored properly with `MULTIPLY`

Answer (score 11):

Here is a quick way to tint your TextView or Button drawable:

```
  private void tintViewDrawable(TextView view) {
        Drawable[] drawables = view.getCompoundDrawables();
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer to use **XML** code instead of **JAVA** you can change the  `android:drawableTint` attribute to `app:drawableTint`.

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin this works for me

```
your_view.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Or if you use a ressource

```
your_view.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this.baseContext, R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_BTNCancel.getBackground().setAlpha(128);
```

it will make the button or any view 50% tint